# Google visualization datatable intermittent problems

Tags: javascript, datatable, google-visualization

I'm using google analytics and visualization library to create a dashboard for our analytics numbers. It was working well, but has started intermittently giving me the **You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView** error. I search on that and found several threads that say other folks couldn't reproduce it or that they weren't loading the libraries correctly. I changed my loading to below (there is a bunch of GA authorization and all that I'm not showing here. But that part all seems to be working.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

...

google.charts.load("current", {packages:["table"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getStarted);

...

gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get(eventsObj).execute(function(results){
    var viz = new google.visualization.Table($('#my-table-id'));
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(results.dataTable);
    viz.draw(dataTable,{showRowNumber:true,allowHtml:true});
});
```

When I look at the results.dataTable from the gapi call it contains the data I would expect. The problem seems to be in converting those results into a DataTable in this line:

```
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(results.dataTable);
```

When I get the message, I don't get any javascript errors in the console. But if I inspect the the datatable returned by that call , there is an array named **Ec** with length zero. When the charting is successful there is an an array called **ec** with a length of 12 (the number of results returned by the request to Google analytics).

Any idea what would cause DataTable(results.dataTable) to not work correctly sometimes?

Comment: the example listed under the [Data Table Class constructor](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1) shows the data format for initializing a table -- can you share a sample of `results.dataTable`?

Comment: I can see it using the debug tools, The data is coming from the embed api for google analytics. It appears to follow the the structure -- object with cols and rows arrays which contain objects with appropriate values.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the second time through the new google.visualization.DataTable() isn't actually creating an instance of a DataTable. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search all kinds of angles and tried a lot of different code, but eventually I found that I should load the libraries like this...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table","corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(getStarted);
```

And the problem has gone away. Don't know if that is right, but it is working for now.